# Making the category & tag Description textarea bigger

Tags: categories, admin

Which files do i edit to make the textarea for tag & cat description bigger?

Or maybe there's an easier way through functions.php to save having to do it every-time i update wp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook onto the edit-tags page and insert some additional styling to adjust the textarea, the ID remains the same for post tags, categories and i think other taxonomies to..

## Adjust CSS for taxonomy management page

Example only, tailor to suit you needs.

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit-tags.php', 'resize_description_field' );
function resize_description_field() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        textarea#tag-description { height:300px!important; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks works well. Also needed textarea#description id for the edit screens.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome.. ;)